# CSS Variables in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, css-variables, ionic4

I am trying to change the color of the icon in the selected tab and am really struggling with how to overwrite the variable.

I'm doing the following:

```
 ion-tabs {
    --color-selected: #ff7800 !important;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ff7800 !important;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code in a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! It looks like --ion-color-contrast stems from the original them that you've applied to the component, in my case "dark". So I actually need to overwrite --ion-color-dark-contrast as follows:

```
 ion-tabs {
    --ion-color-dark-contrast: #ff7800 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a CSS variable for a specific component, add the variable inside of its selector. See Ionic Variables for more information on the component-level variables Ionic provides.

```
/* Set the color on all ion-button elements */
  ion-button {
   --color: #222;
   }

  /* Set the background on an ion-button with the .fancy-button class */
  .fancy-button {
   --background: #00ff00;
  }
```